# Adding new commands with Command Design Pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, command-pattern, open-closed-principle

I'm having a dilemma regarding [Command Design Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html).
Receiver is the interface for a class that knows how to perform operations.

In the example case given in the link, receiver class `Stock Trade` knows how to perform 2 operations, `StockTrade#buy` and `StockTrade#sell`. Those operations correspond to 2 existing commands, `BuyStockOrder` and `SellStockOrder`.

However, what if additional commands would need to be added, for example `FooStockOrder` and `BarStockOrder`? Then, the `Receiver` interface would have to be changed (and all existing implementations), therefore violating the Open-Closed principle.

How to tackle that problem in a way that `Receiver` is (almost) never changed?

Comment: does this help? http://blog.everymansoftware.com/2012/01/command-invoker-pattern-with-openclosed.html

Comment: Not quite, because in the provided example, there is no actual Receiver class, which should be responsinble for actually executing the operations that correspond with commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting your [S.O.L.I.D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles, specifically [Dependancy Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

Don't define your interface in a way that it specifically expects a concrete implimentation like, `BuyStockOrder` or `SellStockOrder`.

Rather define your interface to expect an abstraction like `CommandRequest`, you will then send in concrete implimentations of the `CommandRequest` without ever having to change your interface.

Then your `Receiver` implimentation can decide what to do with it, of course the correct way to deal with this would be using a [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) but I'll leave that up to you.

Here is some code as a simple example:

```
public class Receiver : IReceiver
{
    public CommandResult Process(CommandRequest request)
    {
        // Check the type of request and handle appropriately (or send to who can handle it)

        return new Result();
    }
}

public interface IReceiver
{
    CommandResult Process(CommandRequest request);
}

public abstract class CommandResult
{
    public bool Successful { get; set; }
}

public abstract class CommandRequest
{
}

public class Result : CommandResult
{
}

public class BuyStock : CommandRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

public class SellStock : CommandRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var receiver = new Receiver();
        var result = receiver.Process(new SellStock { Name = "PAYPL", Value = 100.20m });

        Console.WriteLine(result.Successful ? "Yay!" : "Boo!");
    }
}
```